# Courmayeur to Zermatt, no car

Tags: switzerland

suggestions on the best way from Courmayeur to Zermatt in July? we have no international drivers license or car.

Comment: You can plan bus/train rides in Switzerland and other european countries using the SBB website https://www.sbb.ch/en.

Comment: @Janka: Unfortunately, Courmayeur (the Italian ski resort town) doesn't appear to be on their list of places.  The best match is "Vollèges, Cormayeur" which is nowhere near.

Comment: Oh, bummer. Because Trenitalia doesn't do buses, and you need to ride the bus from  Courmayeur to get to a train station.

Comment: There is a bus through the Mont-Blanc-Tunnel, but it may be more scenic to take the cable car over the glacier to Chamonix-Mont-Blanc. From there, you can take the train.

Comment: Do you have no IDP or no driving licence full stop?

Answer (score 2):

There's at least one company that offers transfers from Courmayeur into Switzerland: [Knopkatransfer.com](https://www.knopkatransfer.com/city/courmayeur.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=2017_ENG_Ski_FROM_Only&utm_term=ENG_Courmayeur%20transfer&utm_content=adsid_2017-12-14&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=s&utm_content=239761245754&utm_term=courmayeur%20transport&utm_matchtype=b&utm_adposition=1s4&utm_device=t&utm_devicemodel=&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI2ITXs4D34QIVmQsrCh0tzA9hEAEYBCAAEgJyg_D_BwE). A call to them will get you a price for a transfer to Chamonix via the Mont Blanc tunnel.

From there you can get a train (or rather, a series of trains): https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Chamonix/Zermatt

Disclaimer: this is one possible suggestion based on searches on the internet. I have no affiliations and I make no recommendations.

Comment: Just to add Saada run a bus route between Courmayeur and Chamonix through the tunnel - there is no need to book a taxi: http://www.savda.it/en/67/courmayeur-chamonix/